# Faker.js random word with choices

Tags: javascript, faker.js

I'm trying to use faker.js to generate some random words, but I want it to choose between a few choices.

```
faker.random.word()
```

I tried something like this

```
faker.random.word({constraints: ['','','']})
```

This didn't work, and I could be way off since this was just a straight up guess. I tried looking for documentation on it but couldn't find any. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can generate a number between 0 and the number of words you have and access the words using an array

```js
const words = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
const randomNumber = faker.datatype.number({
    'min': 0,
    'max': words.length - 1
});
console.log(words[randomNumber])
```

Answer (score 1):

Update in Aug'2023:

Since FakerJS v6.3.0, the following 2 methods should do the trick.

1. `faker.helpers.arrayElement` ([doc](https://fakerjs.dev/api/helpers.html#arrayelement))
2. `faker.helpers.arrayElements`  ([doc](https://fakerjs.dev/api/helpers.html#arrayelements))

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anything like this in faker module but you can using `uniqueNamesGenerator` module, check the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unique-names-generator)

```
const { uniqueNamesGenerator } = require('unique-names-generator'); ;
 
const colors = [
  'Green', 'Red', 'Yellow', 'Black'
]
 
const characterName =  uniqueNamesGenerator({
  dictionaries: [colors],
  length: 1
});

console.log(characterName)
```

Answer (score 0):

i was looking for same issue in php , the php way is this :

```
echo $faker->randomElements(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);
```

['c']

Comment: He is looking for something in JS and the `randomElements` is not implemented in `faker.js`